# Prime numbers and gaps of multiplications of triangular numbers

Tags: reference-request, prime-numbers, recreational-mathematics, prime-gaps

Triangular numbers:  $T_n = \frac{n(n+1)}{2} = 1,3,6,10,15,21,28...$

From my observations of the first $10000$ primes:

**For any prime $P$ greater than $3$:**

**Observation 1)** There will always be at least one case that belongs to a minimum of $3$ terms and max $P-1$ terms such that:

$P + 2x⋅T_1 = prime$  (second term)

$P + 2x⋅T_2 = prime$. (third term)

...

$P + 2x⋅T_n = prime$. ($n+1$ term)

**Observation 2)** The only examples I encountered to belong to $P-1$ terms so far, are:

**Several examples for $5$:**

$x = 1$: $5  → 7 → 11  → 17$ ($4$ terms)

$x = 3$: $5  → 11 → 23  → 41$ ($4$ terms)

...

**Several examples for $7$:**

$x = 2$: $7  → 11 → 19  → 31 → 47 → 67$ ($6$ terms)

$x = 5$: $7 → 17  → 37 → 67  → 107 → 157$ ($6$ terms)

...

**Two examples for $11$:**

$x=1$: $11 →  13 →  17 →  23 →  31 →  41 →  53 →  67 →  83 →  101$

($10$ terms)

$x=3$: $11 →  17 →  29 →  47 →  71 →  101 →  137 →  179 → 227 →  281$

($10$ terms)

Almost: $x=6$: $11 →  23 →  47 →  83 →  131 →  191 →  263 →  347 → 443$

($9$ terms)

**One examples for $13$:**

$x=5$: $13 →  23 →  43 →  73 →  113 →  163 →  223 →  293 →  373 →  463 →  563 →  673$

($12$ terms)

**One examples for $17$:**

$x=1$: $17 →  19 →  23 →  29 →  37 →  47 →  59 →  73 →  89 →  107 →  127 →  149 → 173 → 199 → 227 → 257$

($16$ terms)

Almost: $x=6$: $17 →  29 →  53 →  89 →  137 →  197 →  269 →  353 →  449 →  557 →  677 →  809 → 953 → 1109 → 1277$

($15$ terms)

**One examples for $19$:**

$x=2$: $ 19 →  23 →  31 →  43 →  59 →  79 →  103 →  131 →  163 →  199 →  239 → 283 → 331 → 383 → 439 → 499 → 563  →631$

($18$ terms)

**One examples for $23$:**

$x=3$: $ 23 →  29 →  41 →  59 →  83 →  113 →  149 →  191 →  239 →  293 → 353 → 419 → 491 → 569 → 653 → 743 → 839 → 941  →  1049  →  1163  →  1283  →  1409$

($22$ terms)

Almost One examples for $31$:

Almost: $x=6$: $ 31 →  43 →  67 →  103 →  151 →  211 →  283 →  367 →  463 →  571 → 691→ 823 → 967 → 1123 → 1291 → 1471 → 1663 → 1867  →  2083  →  2311  →  2551  →  2803 → 3067 → 3343 → 3631  →3931 →4243 →  4567 →  4903$

($29$ terms)

**One examples for $41$:**

$x=6$: $ 41 →  43 →  47 →  53 →  61 →  71 →  83 →  97 →  113 →  131 → 151→ 173 → 197 → 223→ 251 → 281 → 313 → 347  →  383 →  421  →  461  →  503 → 547 → 593  → 641 → 691 →743 →797 →  853 →  911 →  971 →  1033 →  1097 →  1163 → 1231 → 1301 →  1373 → 1447 → 1523 → 1601$

($40$ terms)

The last case is also known as "Lucky numbers of Euler
" of the form $k^2 − k + 41$:

$41, 43, 47, 53, 61, 71, 83, 97, 113, 131, 151, 173, 197, 223, 251, 281, 313, 347, 383, 421, 461, 503, 547, 593, 641, 691, 743, 797, 853, 911, 971, ...$ (sequence [A005846](https://oeis.org/A005846) in the OEIS).[1](https://oeis.org/A005846)

**Observation 3) For any prime $P$ greater than $11$:**

There will always be at least one case that belongs to a minimum of $3$ terms such that:

$P - 2x⋅T_1 = prime$  (second term)

$P - 2x⋅T_2 = prime$. (third term)

...

$P - 2x⋅T_n = prime$. ($n + 1$ term)

Since I believe none of the assumptions can be proved, any information about these $3$ observations and whether there are any counter examples is appreciated?

Comment: 31 breaks observation 3. Going through $x$, $31-1*6$, $31-2*2$,and $ 31-3*2$  aren’t prime.

Comment: The lucky numbers of Euler are identical to your question when $x=1$.

Comment: @Eric what about $31-(2*1*4) =23$ and $31-(2*1*4)-(2*2*4)=7$ (where $x=4$)?

Comment: Ahh, I’m mistaken (I was counting terms after the initial one).